# V4L2 setting horizontal_flip results in "bar" artifacts

Tags: camera, v4l2

**Camera**: OmniVision OV5645 (MIPI CSI-2 connection)

**MCU**: RK3399

**Linux Kernel version**: 4.4.189

**Driver**: [v4 mainline](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/drivers/media/i2c/ov5645.c)

When I flip the camera horizontally using `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=1`, black vertical bar artifacts begin to appear at all the edges in the image.

**Captured Images for comparison**: [flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hoBD.png) vs [not flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcaEE.png)

Has anyone experienced a similar issue before? I'm not even sure where to begin debugging - is this due to the camera sensor or maybe the rkisp module onboard the rk3399 or something else? I don't have another MCU with a MIPI connection like a Raspberry Pi or something to test it on either.

**Things I've tried that did not work**:

- Editing the OV5645 driver to flip the `isp_mirror` bit when the v4l2 horizontal_flip control is toggled. This not only did not fix the issue but resulted in a completely pink/purple image
- Editing the OV5645 driver to set the default horizontal_flip to 1
- Editing the initial i2c register values in the OV5645 driver to turn off binning

`media-ctl` topology dump:

```
Media controller API version 0.1.0

Media device information
------------------------
driver          rkisp1
model           rkisp1
serial          
bus info        
hw revision     0x0
driver version  0.0.0

Device topology
- entity 1: rkisp1-isp-subdev (4 pads, 6 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown flags 0
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev0
    pad0: Sink
        [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1920x1080 field:none
         crop.bounds:(0,0)/1920x1080
         crop:(0,0)/1920x1080]
        <- "rkisp1_dmapath":0 []
        <- "rockchip-mipi-dphy-rx":1 [ENABLED]
    pad1: Sink
        <- "rkisp1-input-params":0 [ENABLED]
    pad2: Source
        [fmt:YUYV8_2X8/1920x1080 field:none
         crop.bounds:(0,0)/1920x1080
         crop:(0,0)/1920x1080]
        -> "rkisp1_selfpath":0 [ENABLED]
        -> "rkisp1_mainpath":0 [ENABLED]
    pad3: Source
        -> "rkisp1-statistics":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 2: rkisp1_mainpath (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video0
    pad0: Sink
        <- "rkisp1-isp-subdev":2 [ENABLED]

- entity 3: rkisp1_selfpath (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video1
    pad0: Sink
        <- "rkisp1-isp-subdev":2 [ENABLED]

- entity 4: rkisp1_dmapath (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video2
    pad0: Source
        -> "rkisp1-isp-subdev":0 []

- entity 5: rkisp1-statistics (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video3
    pad0: Sink
        <- "rkisp1-isp-subdev":3 [ENABLED]

- entity 6: rkisp1-input-params (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video4
    pad0: Source
        -> "rkisp1-isp-subdev":1 [ENABLED]

- entity 7: rockchip-mipi-dphy-rx (2 pads, 2 links)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown flags 0
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev1
    pad0: Sink
        [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1920x1080 field:none]
        <- "ov5645 2-003c":0 [ENABLED]
    pad1: Source
        [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1920x1080 field:none]
        -> "rkisp1-isp-subdev":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 8: ov5645 2-003c (1 pad, 1 link)
            type V4L2 subdev subtype Sensor flags 0
            device node name /dev/v4l-subdev2
    pad0: Source
        [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1920x1080 field:none
         crop:(0,0)/1920x1080]
        -> "rockchip-mipi-dphy-rx":0 [ENABLED]
```

Comment: Are you talking about the jagged edge on the diagonal lines, which almost looks like interlace artifacts?  That's almost certainly an artifact of binning.  It's flipping pixel pairs, not pixels.  Do you see this if you use the full resolution of the sensor?  What format are you capturing?

Unfortunately, OmniVision is not particularly responsive to support questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Yes exactly, I was referring to the jagged edges that almost look like interlace artifacts. I see, according to media-ctl im using UYVY8_2X8 at 1920x1080. 

According to the ov5645 datasheet, full resolution 2592x1944 is only available at 15 fps and we would like to record video at 30 fps or more. Still, I'll try changing the resolution and seeing how it goes

Comment: I just tried changing the resolution with `media-ctl --set-v4l2 '"ov5645 2-003c":0[fmt:UYVY8_2X8/2592x1944]'`, verified that the resolution had increased and media-ctl topology updated, but the artifacts are still there once I call `v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=1`

Comment: This is very bizarre.  The problem only shows up on sharp edges.  Did you notice the fuzzy edges are just fine?  It's a repeating pattern of 8 columns.  I wrote some code to unflip the columns in various patterns that should work, but whatever improves the sharp edge makes the non-sharp edges bad.  I'm totally confused.

Comment: note that you set the flip on `/dev/video0` which in the topology belongs to `rkisp1_mainpath` entity which is part of the isp. So this might imply that the problem is not in the sensor but in the isp driver. You can check what are the controls supported by the sensor by inquiring `/dev/v4l-subdev2` and see if the sensor itself support flip.

Comment: @dafnahaktana so I did `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/v4l-subdev2 --all` and the controls were the same as `/dev/video0` with the entity info being different and `video0` containing the format video capture details. The controls for the 2 different subdevices seem to be the same thing as `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/v4l-subdev2 --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=1` produced the same artifacts and the image was able to be flipped back using `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=0`

Comment: @billy which kernel source code do you use?

Comment: it's v4.4.189 with the manufacturer's own dts. The som is an OK3399 by Forlinx. I can't find any of their source code online, but it should be similar to https://github.com/96rocks/kernel/blob/release-4.4-rock960/arch/arm64/boot/dts/rockchip/rock960-model-ab-linux.dts, with the camera definitions replaced to match the ov5645:

`ov5645@3c {
  ... // not enough chars to paste here
};`